# Outlier detection with pandas for data with many missing values

Tags: python, pandas, outliers

I have several long-term data series with gaps and want to use a low pass filter to detect outliers. In theory, (data-median) > 3 sigma seems like an appropriate test, but there are two issues with this:

1. the data series are too long and variable, so that using only one median and standard deviation for the entire series doesn't work,
2. using pandas.rolling_median and pandas.rolling_std gets me pretty far already, but now the data gaps become a problem, because the rolling values at the ends of each valid interval are missing, and hence there are no values to compare two.

The problem is illustrated with the following program (you may need to run again if all outliers are captured during the first try due to the random data):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
WINDOW = 72  # rolling window size
#generate random data series
dates = pd.date_range(start='1996-01-01 00:00', end='1996-05-31 23:00', freq='H')
values = np.random.random(size=len(dates))
# add random spikes
idx = np.random.randint(0, len(dates), size=40)
values[idx] = values[idx] * 3.
# set periods to missing
idx = np.random.randint(0, len(dates), size=20)
for i in idx:
    values[i:i+WINDOW] = np.nan
# create pandas series
s = pd.Series(values, index=dates)
s.plot(linestyle='None', marker='o')
# calculate rolling median and standard deviation
rm = pd.rolling_median(s, window=WINDOW, center=True)
rm.plot(linestyle='None', marker='x')
rs = pd.rolling_std(s, window=WINDOW, center=True)
(rm+3.*rs).plot()
# identify outliers as (series-median) > 3*stddev
n = (s-rm).apply(np.abs)
outliers = s[n > 3.*rs]
outliers.plot(linestyle='None', marker='^', color='r')
plt.show()
```

When you run this program you should see that some outliers are not marked with red triangles, because the red line (median + 3 standard deviations) contains no values.

So, my question is: how can I fill the beginnings and ends of each rolling interval with the respective first an dlast valid median value?

To illustrate: suppose my rolling medians are [nan, nan, 2, 4, 3, nan, nan], I wish to obtain [2, 2, 2, 4, 3, 3, 3]. So far I can only think of a cumbersome solution with a loop, but that doesn't feel right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`ffill`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.ffill.html) and [`bfill`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.bfill.html).

`ffill` will propagate the closest value forwards through `nans` and `bfill` will propagate the closest value backwards through `nans`. These are both convenience methods for [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.fillna.html) with the directions specified.

```
s = pd.Series([np.nan, np.nan, 2, 4, 3, np.nan, np.nan])
s = s.ffill().bfill()
print(s)
```

outputs

```
0    2.0
1    2.0
2    2.0
3    4.0
4    3.0
5    3.0
6    3.0
dtype: float64
```

Comment: Yes! This does the trick. However, I add a `limit=WINDOW/2+1` to each ffill() so that the first ffill will not overwrite the beginning of the next valid interval, but instead the bfill values are used there.

Comment: Alternative solution? Set the limit argument of the rolling_median to 1? I guess I am still slightly confused why the default `None` means that all samples must be present...